# How to remove everything between two words in RegEx?

Tags: replace, kate

I want to remove everthing between **.com/** to **?utm**

How can I do that?
I use Notepad++ and Kate.

```
https://www.forexample.com/cat.belt?utm2900&eav=AfbHJya2K7Mbg2mPWatN
https://www.forexample.com/cat.food?utm89748&eav=AfbHJya2K7Mbg2mPWatN
https://www.forexample.com/dog.necklace?utm25875&eav=AfbHJya2K7Mbg2mPWatN
https://www.forexample.com/dog.belt?utm25285&eav=AfbHJya2K7Mbg2mPWatN
https://www.forexample.com/dog.food?utm785844&eav=AfbHJya2K7Mbg2mPWatN
```

I tried to Google the solution, but nothing really works.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you could use `(?:^.*?\.com\/)(.*?)(?:\?utm.*$)` with `$1` matching "cat.belt", "cat.food" etc.

In fact, the only change in comparison to @akash 's answer is that you invert the capturing and non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

try the pattern: `(^.*?\.com\/)(?:.*?)(\?utm.*$)`

substitution: `$1$2`

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/xChAme/2

Comment: Thank you so much. It works but my question was wrong. I'm sorry for that. I was little hurry. I need to keep everything between two word.
cat.belt
cat.food
dog.necklace
I need to keep all this.